# Why is this.props.param.match.id undefined, resulting in Express error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, routes

I am new to Express.js, trying to learn how to use it, and I am trying to grab an id value from this.props.match.params, but it doesn't exist there.

My express route is set up like so:

```
//Edit Member
router.route('/edit/:id').get((req,res, next) => {
    memberSchema.findById(req.params.id, (error, data) => {
     if(error) {
         return next(error)
     } else {
         res.json(data)
     }
    })
})
```

The page URL is "http://localhost:3000/members/edit/5de6dad10844ae2fb875c0d1`

The axios request looks like:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/members/edit/' + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          ign: res.data.ign,
          name: res.data.name,
          role: res.data.role
        });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
```

The Schema looks like:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let memberSchema = new Schema({
    ign: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    role: {
        type: String
    }
}, {
    collection: 'members'
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Member', memberSchema)
```

When I click on a member to edit, I get the terminal express error:
`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Member"`

When I console log `this.props.params` I get this:

```
location: {pathname: "/members/edit/5de6dad10844ae2fb875c0d1", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined, key: "tysqtx"}
match:
isExact: false
params:
__proto__: Object
path: "/members/edit"
url: "/members/edit"
__proto__: Object
staticContext: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

However, when I navigate to `http://localhost:4000/members/edit/5de6dad10844ae2fb875c0d1` I can return the json data directly in the browser from Mongo, where it is running.

Hitting that URL returns:

```
{"_id":"5de6dad10844ae2fb875c0d1","ign":"Test","name":"TestName","role":"Guest","__v":0}
```

My repo is located [here](https://github.com/leesaenz/guild-app-2) if you'd like to clone it and help me figure out why ID is not able to be accessed via express and for more context.  I have been trying to figure this out for a while now, but can't see what is wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated and sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I have been searching high and low.

Comment: Which file is that axios request in? You should probably share the contents of that file in the question rather than providing an external link.

Comment: so, uh, i'd suggest first ensuring that you're actually passing an id. either `console.log(this.props.match.params.id)`, or check the network tab to see the actual request being made. This should rule out either the server-side logic or the client-side logic, allowing you to just focus on one or the other.

Comment: It doesn’t look like you specified url parameters in your Route components, in this case `:id`, why not? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params . React router looks for specific syntax in the route path to determine what url parameters will be available.

Comment: I mean in App.js of the React application that’s using React router Route component. The routes don’t specify that id is a url parameter, therefore match props will be undefined.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thank you! It was something simple and I knew it would be.  It always is.  I was simply missing the id parameter in app.js.  You're awesome.  Do you want to officially answer the question so I can mark it?

Comment: @leesaenz Good to hear! I've create an answer for the solution. Mark if it helped resolve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use [react-router-dom URL Parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) props values in your component code you need to specify them in the `Route` component `path` property. You would need to append `:id` to your members edit route and any other routes you expect to use `props.match.params.id`:

Change:

```
<Route path="/members/edit" />
```

To:

```
<Route path="/members/edit/:id" />
```

It will expose a property with name `id` in `props.match.params` that you can reference in your component code.

It looks like your deleted the temporary repository with the problematic code so this is from memory.